# How do you write Python datetime in JSON format?

Tags: python, json, sqlite, datetime, flask

I'm currently making a Flask app and I'm trying to add inputs to my database through Postman.

This my models.py:

```
from datetime import datetime

class PracticeRecord(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "practice_record"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    minutes = db.Column(db.Integer)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    #userID
```

This is my routes.py:

```
from .import db
from .models import PracticeRecord

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/add_practicerecord', methods=['POST'])
def add_practiceRecord():
    practiceRecord_data = request.get_json()

    new_practiceRecord = PracticeRecord(description=practiceRecord_data['description'], 
                        date=practiceRecord_data['date'], minutes=practiceRecord_data['minutes'])

    db.session.add(new_practiceRecord)
    db.session.commit()

    return 'Done', 201
```

When I put in the JSON data in Postman, I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74rM1.png).
It says that SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input. But isn't:

```
"date": "2020-04-06T14:42:24.996181"
```

already in that format? I'm so confused.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: That's a string, not a `datetime` or `date` object.

Comment: I had some doubts. These concepts are called serialization and deserialization. I am learning the same. I think you should too.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried removing the quotation marks but it ends up failing to decode the JSON object.

Comment: You need to convert the string to a datetime after decoding the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save `datetime` in DB you must create `datetime` object not its string value.  `practiceRecord_data['date']` is the string value of the datetime. use `datetime.strptime`:

```
@main.route('/add_practicerecord', methods=['POST'])
def add_practiceRecord():
    practiceRecord_data = request.get_json()
    datetime = datetime.strptime(practiceRecord_data['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

new_practiceRecord = PracticeRecord(description=practiceRecord_data['description'], 
                    date=datetime, minutes=practiceRecord_data['minutes'])

db.session.add(new_practiceRecord)
db.session.commit()

return 'Done', 201
```

Comment: This may be the solution. This may be ok for understanding but I think this is discouraged. There are serializers and deserializers specifically designed for that.

Comment: @Rahul you mean using something like [flask-serialize](https://pypi.org/project/flask-serialize/) ?

Comment: Yes. Something like that. I don't use flask as yet so I can't recommend anything. You will have to search for it your self which one suits your need.

Comment: Thanks @shotgunner, your solution worked, gonna use this in the meantime

Comment: @Rahul thanks too, I've searched more about flask-serialize but sadly haven't gotten it to work yet, so I'm gonna stick with the other solution for now